# Position vector without origin

Tags: vectors

There is a question of how to prove Ceva's theorem using vectors. I looked at the reference answer and I am so confused about it. Here are the question and a part of the reference answer(The following text is translated from a book written in Japanese. I'm sorry if it's weird to read):

**Question:**

Complete the following proof. For a triangle ABC, X, Y, and Z are three points on BC, CA, AB, respectively. The segments AX, BY and CZ intersect at one point. The necessary and sufficient conditions of that is $\displaystyle \frac{BX}{XC} \times \frac{CY}{YA} \times \frac{AZ}{ZB} \ =\ 1$

**A part of the reference answer:**
[image]

Suppose that the position vectors of A, B and C are a, b, c.

$\displaystyle \overrightarrow{BX} =l\overrightarrow{XC} ,\ \overrightarrow{CY} =m\overrightarrow{YA} ,\ \overrightarrow{AZ} =n\overrightarrow{ZB}$

so the position vectors of X, Y, and Z are $\displaystyle \frac{b+lc}{l+1} ,\ \frac{c+ma}{m+1} ,\frac{a+nb}{n+1}$（I can't get it）

**Please help:**

The definition of position vector from wiki:

> In geometry, a position or position vector, also known as location
> vector or radius vector, is a Euclidean vector that represents the
> position of a point P in space in relation to an arbitrary reference
> origin O.

So where is the origin O in this question and how to understand the position vectors of X, Y, and Z

Comment: I think "are compared to one point" is a transation flaw and should be "intersect at one point". Also, with your definition of position vector you need to specify the origin, but it seems that for some higher level od abstraction it could be irrelevant. The use od 1's seems to be a little abused, but valid as they appear later only on respected ratios

Comment: The "1" in each side of the triangle looks wrong. (1) Imagine that l,m,n are very large. Then X will be close to C , Y will be close to A , Z will be close to B. Then we will not get Intersection at Single Point in the "Center". (2) Alternatively, Consider that the triangle has very small sides, smaller than "1", then l,m,n will be negative. (3) Only when we know this Correction, we can make the ratios work out.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have updated the post. What's the meaning of od? It seems to be an abbreviation. @Esgeriath

Comment: You can put $O$ anywhere you want. The formulas for the various points will come out the same.

Comment: I agree with that. There is an implicit condition like you said  (1), which doesn't correspond to the condition of the question. @Prem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > [image]
> >
> > Suppose that the position vectors of $A, B, C$ are $a, b, c.$
>
> where is the origin $O$ in this question? why is $\displaystyle \frac{b+lc}{l+1}$ the position vector of $X\,?$

Explicitly: Let $O$ be **an arbitrary** reference origin, and $a,b,c$ be the **corresponding** position vectors of $A,B,C,$ respectively.

Then the position vector of $X$ is
\begin{align}\vec{OX}&=\vec{OC}+\vec{CX}
\\&=\vec{OC}+\frac{1}{l+1}\vec{CB}
\\&=\vec{OC}+\frac{1}{l+1}\left(\vec{OB}-\vec{OC}\right)
\\&=\frac{l\vec{OC}+\vec{OB}}{l+1}
\\&=\frac{b+lc}{l+1},
\end{align} as required.